# output formatting in prolog

Tags: formatting, prolog

i have some facts in prolog.I want to define a rule that would print data about all amino acids in a formated way. here is the link that i have facts and some rules that i have defined myself. but i can not get formatting work , i mean i don't want to use multiple write()'s and even the tab formatting i cant get to work. here is my some logic but its not working. I just want to generate a report like format. Here is the link and code that i tried ***http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/aminnoo.pl***

```
>   aminoname(_,H,ShortName),
>     
>     write(H),
>     write(ShortName),nl,    /* write(ShortName),
>    
>     %display [Hydropathy value]
>     %format:aminoclass('Ala','Hydropathy','hydrophobic').
>     aminoclass(ShortName,'Hydropathy',HydropathyValue),
>     write(HydropathyValue),
> 
>     %display [Volume]
>     %format:aminoclass('Ala','Volume','very small').
>     aminoclass(ShortName,'Volume',VolumeValue),
>      write(VolumeValue),
> 
>     %display [chemical value
>     %format:aminoclass('Ala','Chemical','aliphatic').
>     aminoclass(ShortName,'Chemical',ChemicalValue),   write(ChemicalValue),nl,
>     listAminoAcidProperties(T).*/
>     listAminoAcidProperties(T).
```

i want it in this format

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| name            |    age    |    color      |    something      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  xyz            |     56    |    hgchc      |     var           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i am using this code:

```
format('+~`-t~78|+ ~n', []),
format('|~tTable Title~t~78||~n', []),
format('+~`-t~78|+ ~n', []).

format('| ~s~t~28|| ~s~t~36|| ~s~t~56|| ~s~t~80||~n', 

                            ['Name', 'Age', 'Eye Colour', 'Phone Number']).
```

but it is notgiving output as defined above

Comment: `write` is pretty low level. Have you looked at SWI's other output formatting predicates? See SWI Prolog [Formatted Write](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=format)

Answer (score 3):

[`format/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2) is a predicate that lets you format output in a similar fashion to the `printf` C function.

Comment: i tried it but its not working.an example would be enough

Comment: @kshitijsingh well give me an example of what output you want.

Comment: i am trying this but it is not as expected , not properly formatted
formatOutput:-
    `format('+~`-t~78|+ ~n', []),`
    format('|~tAmino Acid~t~78||~tShort Name~t~78||~tHydropathy value ~t~78||~tVolume~t~78||~tChemical Value~t~78|~n', []),
    format('+~`-t~78|+ ~n', []),
    format('| ~s~t~70|| ~s~t~36|| ~s~t~56|| ~s~t~80||~n', 
           ['Name', 'Age', 'Eye Colour', 'Phone Number']).`

Comment: Please edit your question with an example of the output you **expect** to see. This comment is very difficult to read.